# Catch NSFileHandleOperationException in Swift

Tags: swift, exception

How can I catch a `NSFileHandleOperationException` in Swift?

I use `fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile()` which calls (according to the documentation) `fileHandle.readDataOfLength()` which can throw (again according to the documentation) a `NSFileHandleOperationException`.

How can I catch this exception? I tried

```
do {
    return try fH.readDataToEndOfFile()
} catch NSFileHandleOperationException {
    return nil
}
```

but Xcode says

> Warning: No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression
>
> Warning: 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block

How do I do this?

Edit:
I just decided to use C's good old `fopen`, `fread`, `fclose` as a workaround:

```
extension NSMutableData {
    public enum KCStd$createFromFile$err: ErrorType {
        case Opening, Reading, Length
    }
    
    public static func KCStd$createFromFile(path: String, offset: Int = 0, length: Int = 0) throws -> NSMutableData {
        let fh = fopen(NSString(string: path).UTF8String, NSString(string: "r").UTF8String)
        if fh == nil { throw KCStd$createFromFile$err.Opening }
        defer { fclose(fh) }
    
        fseek(fh, 0, SEEK_END)
        let size = ftell(fh)
        fseek(fh, offset, SEEK_SET)
    
        let toRead: Int
        if length <= 0 {
            toRead = size - offset
        } else if offset + length > size {
            throw KCStd$createFromFile$err.Length
        } else {
            toRead = length
        }
    
        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(toRead)
        defer {
            memset_s(buffer, toRead, 0x00, toRead)
            buffer.destroy(toRead)
            buffer.dealloc(toRead)
        }
        let read = fread(buffer, 1, toRead, fh)
        if read == toRead {
            return NSMutableData(bytes: buffer, length: toRead)
        } else {
            throw KCStd$createFromFile$err.Reading
        }
    }
}
```

`KCStd$` (abbreviation for KizzyCode Standard Library) is the prefix because extensions are module-wide. The above code is hereby placed in Public Domain

I'll leave this open because it's nonetheless an interesting question.

Comment: Did you eventually figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I just decided to use C's good old fopen, fread, fwrite, fclose... They are available in the "Darwin"-module and work seamlessly with Swift-pointers. It might not work in iOS (I don't know), but for OS X it works perfekt even it is a bit more code.

Comment: So, I also added my code.

Comment: Generally when you find an answer to your own question, you post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Well, I don't really think, that this is an answer; I think this would rather count as workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be that you can't. If you look at the declarations in FileHandle, you will see comment:

```
/* The API below may throw exceptions and will be deprecated in a future version of the OS.
 Use their replacements instead. */
```

Comment: Ah ok, this is new. The problem was that the underlying code threw an Obj-C exception which is incompatible to Swifts exception mechanism. To catch this exception you’d need an Obj-C `@try … @catch`-block.

Comment: I suspected the comment/deprecation was new. I ran into the same thing with some code using this that was crashing (because it couldn't catch the objective-c exception). I ended up rewriting it using other apis instead after going down a rabbit hole and eventually finding this header comment. Figured I'd save anyone else the trouble :)

Comment: So what are their replacements exactly?